# Most efficient way to modify an Eloquent query such that it always returns the empty collection?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-optimization

I frequently encounter the programming pattern which takes a Eloquent Query object and adds a filter condition to it. (You may think of a filter as a scope, if you like.) This mostly happens in the context of authorization, whether an authenticated user may or may not see certain subsets of a result.

The pattern looks like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

public function applyFilter(Builder $query): Builder {
  $model = $query->getModel();
  if (!($model instanceof MyModel)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('the given query does not query for <MyModel>');
  }
  $user = Auth::user();
  return $query->where(function (Builder $subquery) use ($user) {
      // Add some filter conditions to the query
      // Typically those depend on the currently authenticated user,
      // privileges of the user and and some properties of the model.
    });
}
```

Sometimes it happens to be already clear that the query must not return any result, just from inspecting the `$user` object or some other property like the state of the application, even without querying for the actual models. In those cases, the filter function above adds a condition to the query which always evaluates to `false` like `->where('1', '=', '2')` or similar. Although, this does the trick and works perfectly, it feels wrong. Eloquent still queries the DB back-end and receives the (expected) empty result.

*Primary question:*

Is there a way, how one could tell Eloquent that a query is known to return the empty result and that no actual query must be made, but that `->get` (and friends) simply return an empty collection? I am thinking of a method like `$query->toNoOp()` or similar.

*Further question:*

Moreover, also consider the case where the construction above is used as part of a more complex query and happens to end up in a sub-query. For example consider the following case:

```php
$relatedModels = MyRelatedModel::query()
  ->where(...)
  ->whereHas('my_model', $q => applyFilter($q))
  ->get();
```

At the moment, this construction results into the rather complicated SQL query

```php
SELECT *
FROM my_related_models
WHERE
  ...
  AND
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM my_models
    WHERE
      my_models.id = my_related_models.model_id
      AND
      1 = 2
  );
```

Although, this again returns the expected empty result, it would be much better if the fact that the inner query is a "no-op" could be propagated to the outer query. In other words, if a sub-query is used within an `EXIST` clause (constructed by `->whereHas` and friends) and this sub-query is known to be a "no-op" query, then the outer query should also become a "no-op" query.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the query is invalid, you should not even run the query / execute it. Just make your API return empty array.

```
public function index() {
   if (! $this->shouldRunQuery(auth()->user())) {
       return response()->json([]);
   }

   return response()->json(Model::query()->get());
}
```

In your sub question, you can execute queries depending on conditions with when(), this is thou handled by `Laravel` and not by `SQL`.

```
Model::query()
    ->when($this->shouldRunQuery(auth()->user()), function ($query)         { 
        // your complex query
    })
->get();
```

In general, you seem very fascinating about solving the problem in `SQL`, instead of handling conditions and states even before the `SQL` is executed. I have seen a lot, but never seen anyone execute this approach.

Comment: i'm not certain i misunderstand the problem or you have looked at it the wrong way :) else clearly enlighten me if this approach could be wrong.